# Can't activate MySQL database on XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This seems to be a common problem and I've tried searching for an answer and attempted to fix my problem based on people's answers, but with no success.

The other day, I started  my local XAMPP server and MySQL database and tried to access phpMyAdmin, but I got the error "Cannot load mysql extension. Please check your PHP configuration". The MySQL extensions in the php.ini file are all uncommented. I am really lost as to what has happened as it was working properly the day before. If I need to provide any more info, please let me know. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the version of PHP, the MySQL extension is deprecated so you shouldn't be using it anyway. Use mysqli or pdo_mysql

Comment: I have all three uncommented in the php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP installs Apache, PHP and Mysql which works out of the box. You must have some other PHP.ini which is interfering with XAMPP. See phpinfo() to find out which PHP.ini is being used.

Check in Program Files if PHP is installed separately. Remove this one.

Comment: I have only one php.ini and phpinfo() shows the Configuration File (php.ini) Path is C:\Windows and the Loaded Configuration File as C:\xampp\php\php.ini